# magento 2 - call payment method render function after discount has been applied

Tags: magento2, checkout, discount, knockoutjs

i defined a function RecalculatePlan in *`/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/installment-method.js` that recalculates the installments displayed in a table contained in the method section. 
I can call the function when the user changes payment method (i bound the event in my template html ).

My problem is: when the user applies a discount in the checkout page i would like to recalculate the installment table of the current selected method. 
How can i call this function? I have no idea how to access the js component.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When a customer applies a discount the quote also updates, so you need listening quote updates.

In your custom js component (`/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/installment-method.js`) subsribe quote totals updates:

```
initObservable: function () {
    this._super();

    quote.totals.subscribe(function () {
        var total = quote.totals()['base_grand_total'];

        // other custom logic
    });

    // other custom logic

    return this;
}
```

Where `quote` is `Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote` js component.